# React : Cannot fetch data if multiple conditions on API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I'm going insane over this one. The api data is returning correctly when using postman, but for some reason in React I cannot get the data. While experimenting I noticed that if I pass only one condition in the api I will get the response back in React, but when passing two I cannot. Keep in mind this is only happening in react, so the API in postman is returning the response perfectly.

React Snippet:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const { data: response } = await axios.get('/api/activity/suggested');
            setData(response);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
          setLoading(false);
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
```

Mongoose api :

```
    router.get('/suggested', auth, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    
        const activity = await Activity.find({
          event: 'suggest_to_user',
          user: req.user.id,
        })
          .sort({ date: -1 })
          .populate([
            {
              path: 'user',
            },
            {
              path: 'ref_following',
            },
            {
              path: 'ref_request',
            },
            {
              path: 'ref_review',
              populate: [
                {
                  path: 'suggestion',
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: 'ref_collection',
              populate: [
                {
                  path: 'user',
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: 'ref_suggestion',
            },
          ]);
    
        res.json(activity);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
      }

});
```

Removing a condition here make it work in React:

```
 const activity = await Activity.find({
          event: 'suggest_to_user',
          user: req.user.id,
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you call the API from your to react app. It doesn't find the id of the user. Try to send authorization user info through the header. Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: You are correct ! But I don't understand how `user: req.user.id` alone is working in the API, but when paired with a second condition like `event: 'suggest_to_user'` I will have to pass the user manually, any ideas ?

Comment: when you are calling `await axios.get('/api/activity/suggested')` put a header of the authorization stage with it. like `const header = {Authorization: auth_token(which will have the id of the user)}` and then send  `await axios.get('/api/activity/suggested', header)` like this. this may help for your solution.

Comment: @SiamAhnaf  It seems you want to expand this answer substantially. I suggest you post your own answer instead.